# Does Phoenix-Spark API have a checkAndPut method like HBase API?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using Spark 1.3, HBase 1.1 and Phoenix 4.4. I have this in my code:

```
val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
dataframe.save("org.apache.phoenix.spark", SaveMode.Overwrite,
    Map("table" -> "TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_HTABLE", "zkUrl" -> zkQuorum))
```

CREATED_DATE is always set to DateTime.now() in the dataframe.

I don't want the field to be updated if the row already exists in HBase, yet there's an update in other fields.

I can achieve it using HBase's checkAndPut: Put all the fields and use checkAndPut on created_date field.

But how do I do that using Phoenix-Spark API? Should I use HBase API instead?

Comment: if you have advance level questions regarding phoenix spark integration, i would suggest you should join Phoenix mailing list. There are much more people to answer these kind of questions.

Comment: When I tried to post my question there, it opens up my mail (To:user@phoenix.apache.org) and I got a return email from Apache Mailer-daemon -fail.

Comment: did you subscribe to mailing list? You will need to subscribe it before sending email to it.

Answer (score 0):

`Approach1:` In this case, you should check whether the row exists or not. If the row exists, then remove CREATED_DATE column from your dataframe.
`Approach2:` If you cant remove  CREATED_DATE column from dataframe, then you will need to write a prePut Coprocessor that will run before doing any puts on the region server. This appraoch will be slightly harder. So, i would suggest 1st approach.

Comment: I can't do the first approach since I am applying only one schema to the dataframe before saving

Comment: @sophie: if you think that my reply answered your question then acknowledge by accepting answer.

Comment: Hi Anil, I'm not sure how Coprocessors work. But I am able to achieve it using HBase's checkAndPut. I'm just not sure how to implement it using Phoenix-Spark API.